# C# Installer Shortcut StartIn Property

Tags: c#

I have a C# project that I've created an installer for.

I've read the instructions on how to add a shortcut to the primary output file of my project to the startup and start menu folders.  This works well.

The problem is that I need the `StartIn` property of the shortcut to be a specific folder on the clients machine (not the default value).  I can manually go in and edit this property, but I have to deploy this on several machines.

The `startin` directory I'm trying to point to is always the same (on all computers), but I can't seem to figure out how to set the `StartIn` property on the shortcut to point to that directory.

Suggestions?

Comment: What installer are you using?  I think that will play a big part in how its set up.  Also, post what you've tried so far if that is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I actually figured it out.

I'm using the built-in C# Installer class in VS Studio 2010.

- In the File System on Target Machine panel (on the left) I right-clicked and selected Add Custom Folder.
- In the properties of that folder, I put the target directory I'm trying to get my shortcut to start in (call it the working folder).
- I then went over to my shortcut in the start menu folder and set the Working Folder property to the folder I just created.

Once I built it and ran the installer... it appears that the Start In property of the shortcut is now using the working directory I specified, instead of the default value.  There may be another way to do this, but this seemed to work for me.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out, mark this as answer when you're able.